# Help identifying a replacement for this discontinued LED, please?

Tags: led, identification

I am looking for a replacement for a discontinued LED. The old part number is Panasonic LNJ801LPDJA, and the datasheet can be viewed here:

[View the Datasheet](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/2/353/LNJ801LPDJA-pdf.php)

The old LED is orange in colour, however, I am looking for a blue replacement.

Would anyone be able to tell me the relevant info that I would need to look for when looking for a new LED that would work? I don't know which info I need from the datasheet in order to be able to source a new one e.g. voltage, size, etc.

Comment: A 3.2 mm Lens on a 5mm lead pitch with only 10 mcd and 90 deg angle in blue , or brighter. How many 1? 1k?

Comment: Well, I would need about 70 of them?

Comment: WHy choose an obsolete short package when SMT are better ?    Kingsbright makes a 5mm lens and 5mm h instead of 3.2 lens 4 mm high but only 2.54 mm lead pitch

Comment: They are to fit on the following button board for a synth. The LEDs fit under keys, so would these replacements you mentioned be EXACTLY the same size? If so, could you link me to the suitable replacement please? That would be awesome! :) 
[link]https://www.keyboardkountry.com/panel-switch-board-for-roland-xp-50-with-ribbon-connectors/

Comment: nothing is the same size, so you must show details to retrofit

Comment: Nothing that is even smaller that would do the job?

Comment: not without space constraints, bias current limit R , solder pads  etc. This is unusual short but double wide lead space

Comment: Closest match is https://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/WP9294QBC-D.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Tony, I really appreciate your advice my friend :)

Comment: Just one more thing, if I may? The link you gave - that is exact in terms of voltage, etc? it is just the size I need to worry about?

Comment: Do not deviate handling from spec. Solder time must be <=3sec, 5W abs max , soldering with stress on bent leads will break gold wirebond

Comment: Gotcha - so very quick solder, low power, and if the size is ok, those ones you linked me to will be fine. Excellent, thanks mate :)

Comment: No you must determine current from R and Vc values  for desired brightness as blue voltage is a bit higher  and brightness much higher

Comment: 3s is your soldering skill not the part. Same with all thruhole LEDs

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Well, thank you so much for your time and help - it has given me a starting point ;) Thanks man!

Comment: Don’t use X methods, it will break inside 20um gold wirebond

Comment: No problem, I see I have to do more research, based on the blue being different values. Thanks again :)

Comment: If 5V start with 470 ohms then adjust

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful :) Cheers!

Comment: Which synthesizer? Link to schematics? But do understand that replacing orange LED with blue may not work because blue LEDs need much more voltage to light up. You may need to replace the series resistors as well to adjust the brightness, or if the LEDs use 3.3V as the supply voltage then they may not even light up.

Comment: @Justme - Assuming the LED supply voltage is 5 volts or greater (which is entirely reasonable for a circuit which uses so old an LED) the LED current will be slightly less than the original circuit. However, at 20 mA the new LED will be ~100 times brighter than the old one. So, yeah, "You may need to replace the series resistors as well to adjust the brightness".

Comment: Thanks for the comments :) It is a Roland XP50 from the mid-nineties. Based on all the great answers, it might be an idea just to source an old board and take them from that, and forget the "blue" idea ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ***Physical measurements***
  Are obviously the most important parameter. A 3.2mm lens with 5mm pitch is something of an oddball part. The most common lens sizes are 3mm and 5mm. The pitch is almost always 2,54mm (0.1'').

  Depending on how critical this is, maybe you can use a 3mm or 5mm lens part and widen the pitch by using through-hole "lead bender" tool. Or go look for 5mm pitch parts, but that will narrow down your options dramatically.

  This is where you may get urges to go have a *polite conversation* with the person who specified such an exotic part to begin with... :)
- ***Luminous intensity (candela)***
  The main issue with your part is that it's so old - you won't find LEDs with just 10mcd today. Meaning that a replacement part might shine some hundred times brighter! You can compensate for this by changing the series resistor though. And end up drawing far less current than your original part.

  (In some rare cases this might actually cause EMC issues since more current = more robust to noise. If you have to change the series resistor from 1k to several 100k, then it may affect EMC.)
- ***Forward voltage and current***
  Forward voltage affects forward current and thereby brightness as well. If you mean to switch from orange to blue then you'll likely get a higher forward voltage too. This can be an issue in case you supply it with 3V3, because some LEDs have too high forward voltage for that!

  While forward voltage will vary a lot between parts, the optimal forward current is almost always 20mA, it's an industry de facto reference current. If you look at your current part, it specifies all conditions with I<sub>F</sub> = 20mA - meaning forward current. Lower current means lower luminous intensity (and it's not necessarily a linear equation).

  Again, you can experiment with the series resistor to find the optimal value.
- ***View angle***
  It's typically somewhere around 30 dgr to 90 dgr.
- ***Lens type*** Clear or diffused.

The other parameters like wavelength are probably not critical in your case. If the specification is "blue" then just look for that. For manufacturing, soldering temperatures matter a lot, it's quite easy to damage LEDs if given too much heat, but that's more of a parameter that you need to inform the assembly contractor about. Be especially careful about this if you intend to buy from fishy manufacturers nobody has heard of.

Comment: Brilliant advice there, thanks so much for that! I am sure anyone else who finds this and has been looking for replacement LEDs for a similar thing will find it so useful! These LEDs are part of a Roland XP50 synth from the mid-nineties. As is often the case with these kinds of things, they seem to use the most annoying parts possible :) Thanks again for your help! :)